# Local minimum example

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Help me please with this question.

Let's $\Delta u>0$  in connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Is it possible that function $u$ have local minimum? Can you show an example?

Thanks!!

Comment: You've asked seven questions, all of which are stated as "Help me please with this question - some question - thanks". No motivation, no context, no thinking beforehand. If you've done some work, show it; otherwise, it's time for you to do some effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Thank you! But $\Delta u$ is defined by $\Delta u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial x_{i}^2}$, can I use $u(x)=x^2$ in this case?

Comment: @Mushka Yes, that will do, too. T